# SAS: Getting variable name of last non-zero observation

Tags: sas

I'm trying to figure this out. I have a table as follows and I'm trying to populate the final column with the variable name of the last non-zero value (as shown in final column):

```
ID  MTH_1   MTH_2   MTH_3   MTH_4   MTH_5   MONTH_LAST_BALANCE
--------------------------------------------------------------
1   10      0       10      20      10      MTH_5
2   5       10      15      5       0       MTH_4
3   5       10      5       0       0       MTH_3
4   1       2       3       1       0       MTH_4
5   1       0       0       0       0       MTH_1
```

I'm guessing I need to use some sort of array to make this work but I don't know. As per row 1, I need the *last* non-zero value only, not the left-most one that some other code seems to retrieve.

Any help would be much appreicated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data want ;
  set have ;

  /* Load MTH_1 to MTH_5 into array */
  array m{*} MTH_1-MTH_5 ;

  length MONTH_LAST_BALANCE $5. ;

  /* Iterate over array */
  do i = 1 to dim(m) ;
    /* Use vname function to get variable name from array element */
    if m{i} > 0 then MONTH_LAST_BALANCE = vname(m{i}) ;
  end ;
run ;
```